# Consulta sobre fechas y horas en angular

Tags: angular

Buenas compañeros tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con una pagina web realizada en angular con sql server, basicamente la funcion de la pagina es realizar consultas en base a una query con parametros la duda que tengo es sobre el formato que devuelven las fechas y horas por ejemplo en la bd figura asi 2018-08-01 11:27:54.930

Pero en la pagina al hacer la consulta figura asi 2018-08-01T11:27:54.930Z, con una T y una Z como podria hacer para que ya no salga de esa manera, debo mencionar que en el query agregue un convert pero al hacer la consulta en la pagina ya no me devolvia nada

el convert lo tenia de la siguiente manera CONVERT(varchar(30), fecha,21)

Comment: Hola, No soy experto en el lado del backend pero al igual que tu cuando hago consultas que obtengo una fecha me viene ese formato, del lado del cliente para hacer el parse a la fecha utilizamos la libreria de [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: gracias por el dato amigo, lo voy a probar con los campos de fecha